# Universal group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, terminology

I can construct a finitely presented group $G$ with the following property (which I use to construct something else).

> Given a finitely preseted group $\Gamma$, there is a subgroup $G'\le G$ of finite index
> such that  $$\Gamma=G'/\langle\mathrm{Tor}\, G'\rangle ,$$ where $\mathrm{Tor}\, G'\subset G'$ is the set of all elements of finite order.

I think to call such group $G$ *universal*.

**Questions:**

- Was it already constructed?
- Does it already has a name? Is there any closely related terminology?

---

**P.S.**

- The group which I construct is in fact hyperbolic.
- The construction is simple, but it takes 2--3 pages. Let me know if you see a short way to do it.
- [Here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/k332884x7m10l654/), the term "universal group" was used in very similar context (thanks to D. Panov for the reference).
- Thanks to all your comments, we call them ["telescopic" actions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4814) now.

Comment: I advise against the word "universal", without more context at least.  Call it Anton-universal or the Petrunin-Swiss-Army Group, or some useful modification of some synonym for "universal".  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.03.30

Comment: Well, Swiss-Army Group is a nice name. But why not universal? --- after quick search I did not see that term "universal group" is used...

Comment: I think "universal finitely-presented group" is OK: you claim that any finitely presented group is a subquotient, which although not quite a universal property http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Formal_definition isn't too far removed.  But certainly there are non-finitely-presented groups that you're not capturing.

Comment: The closest condition I've heard of is "SQ-universal":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQ_universal_group

Your group satisfies a very strong form of "SQ-universal in the class of finitely presented groups". 



Comment: This property seems far too specific to be called simply "universal". I'd go with something like "TQ-universal".  If you want to know whether someone else has done this, I'd try looking at the work of Olshanskii and his students.

Comment: Anton, by a "universal finitely presented group" one usually means a finitely presented group that contains each finitely presented group as a subgroup. Such groups can be constructed via Higman's embedding theorem. If $Q$ is such a group, it is possible to cook up a hyperbolic group $G$ such that $Q$ is a quotient of $G$, and the kernel is normally generated by elements of finite order. This is of course not the same as what you do. 

Comment: @Anton, would you tells us how the group $G$ is constructed?

Comment: @Igor, Take a figure eight with generators $a$ and $b$. Glue four 2-cells along words $a$, $b$, $ab$ and $ab^{-1}$. (The obtained space is simply connected.) Now, choose 3 points in each 2-cell and make each to be a double orbi-point. The obtained orbi-space has needed fundamental group.  

Comment: @Anton, would you explain what makes the group universal? 

Comment: @Igor. It is a direct construction, but it takes about 2-3 pages to write...

Comment: Anton, usually for a "universal group" the input is a finite presentation, for example, the above mentioned universal finitely presented group starts with the free product of all finitely presented groups, which is recursively presented, and then embeds it into a finitely presented group. Similarly, in a Rips construction one starts with a finite presentation and adds/modifies relations. I just wish to see where all finite presentations come in?

Comment: Anton: Am I right and your group is given by the presentation $\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3, z_1, z_2, z_3, t_1, t_2, t_3| u^2=1 \hbox{(for all generators)}, x_1x_2x_3y_1y_2y_3=z_1z_2z_3, x_1x_2x_3(y_1y_2y_3)^{-1}=t_1t_2t_3\rangle$ ? Such groups have not been constructed before. It is not possible to call them "universal" for the reasons given to you by Igor. The term has been used already for something else. 

Comment: Such a group is necessarily Large (Large in the sense of Gromov/Pride) also (this implies SQ-universal, along with a number of other properties). See this paper of Button for more details, http://www.springerlink.com/content/u014p6u2w4560786/

Comment: @Alan @Mark @Igor @HW @Agol @Anton Could someone write in an answer to move the question to answered status?

Comment: How come now "telescopic" has become "all-inclusive"?

Comment: @YangMills, I think "all-inclusive" describes the property better, although "telescopic" sounds better.

Comment: It is probably self-understood but the words "torsion free" are missing, right?

Comment: "universal" seems to become a universal terminology...

Comment: @AntonPetrunin The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...

Comment: Another link to `springerlink.com` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19895/universal-group#comment121736_19895) above seems to be broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Аnswered to move the question to *answered status*.

We decided to use the term **telescopic action**.

Thank you all for your comments they were helpful for me and Dima.